# Loading SQLite extensions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite

I have an extension which can be loaded in SQLite using the `load_extension` function. It would be useful for me if I could load it in QGIS to use in queries made via Database Manager.

The Python SQLite binding prohibits loading extensions by default. Could I do something from the Python console or project macro to load an extension?

I have QGIS 2.4.0 with spatialite 4.1.1, python-spatialite 3.0.1, python 2.7.8 and sqlite3 3.8.5. I have tried running the `select load_extension('...')` from DB Manager and it does not work (gives error "Authorization required"; because it is prohibited by default by python sqlite bindings). I don't know how to get the connection from the python console to do anything with it.

Comment: Please provide more information about your OS, version of QGIS, how it was installed, and what you have already tried.

Comment: @dakcarto: I have added versions and what I tried. Operating system does not matter; this is internal behaviour of qgis and the python bindings it uses.